# How to add or function in while loop

Tags: java

I want to perform an OR operation in while loop so I have Data in excel sheet like this ----> Nom du Client/Nom deu Client so now I want to search in while loop such that if Nom du Client does not exist it has to execute Nom deu Client so I have done like this but now I am not getting OR operation

```
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null || (s = br.readLine()) == "||")
            {
            s.split(s);
            if (s.contains(keyword)) {
                s = s.replaceAll(keyword, " ");
                System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Do you mean something like an if then else if statement? If (Nom du Client) then do abc ELSE IF (Nom deu Client) do def

Comment: yes but it has to read we are not specifying that explicitly so help me

Comment: The s is a keyword which holds the data which is been read by excel and it will search with respect to keyword